# Error MediaProjection when targetSdkVersion 29

Tags: android, mediaprojection

I am building a screen recording application. But it only works on targetSdkVersion 28, when passing targetSdkVersion 29 requested by google, the error

Code

```
 @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Screen Cast Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();

        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
```

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster, PID: 21862
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster/com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
        at com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:426)
```

Thank so much!!!!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
`

Comment: @blackapps how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Use a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION. Thank so much!!!!

Comment: @blackapps You can give me a specific code? Thanks!

Comment: No i cant. Sorry. Thanks. Thank so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new service attribute added in API 29, and apparently `MediaProjection` requires a foreground service to be used since the exception clarifies that. Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a service,
2. Add the service to your manifest,
3. In the manifest, at your service, add `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"`
4. Move your media projection code from your activity to the service.
5. Start the service from your activity which will start the media projection in the service.

Note that foreground services require a persistent notification and a notification channel for API 26 or above.

Comment: How to getMediaProjection on Class MyService and Return MainActivity? Thanks Bro!